# mysql query for upcoming event with start date and end date and show past event

Tags: php, mysql

I have a event table which start and end date stored like follows

```
 event_id   eventstartdate    eventenddate 
    1       2012-10-02         2012-10-20 
    2       2013-09-27         2013-10-27 
    6       2013-10-18         2013-11-18 
    8       2012-11-06         2012-11-23 
    9       2013-02-05         2013-02-12 
    10      2013-06-11         2013-06-13
```

and i want to show the event order by the event start date from today..and get the past event based on the event start date in single query..

Expected result as follows

```
event_id   eventstartdate    eventenddate
      1      2013-09-27         2013-10-27 
      2      2013-10-18         2013-11-18
      3      2013-06-11         2013-06-13
      4      2013-02-05         2013-02-12
      5      2012-11-06         2012-11-23 
      6      2012-10-02         2012-10-20
```

Comment: Can you show expected results?

Comment: @xQbert m edited the question with expected result can u take a look?

Comment: Original events were 1,2,6,8,9,10  Now events are 1-6 in order.  it appears your starting data lacks correlation to your expected results. making it very difficult for me and it appars others, to understand what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) to get actual data and then select all rows which are before the current data and then use [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) to order in descending order from today

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE eventstartdate < CURDATE()
ORDER BY eventstartdate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I doubt this is what you're after.  I need to see expected results to better understand the question.

```
SELECT Event_ID, EventStartDate, EventEndDate 
FROM Table
ORDER BY EventStartDate
```

Comment: `event_id   eventstartdate    eventenddate
      1      2013-09-27         2013-10-27 
      2      2013-10-18         2013-11-18
      3      2013-06-11         2013-06-13
      4      2013-02-05         2013-02-12
      5      2012-11-06         2012-11-23 
      6      2012-10-02         2012-10-20`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with this Query

```
SELECT * FROM 
  table 
ORDER BY eventstartdate DESC
```

According to me it will give you all the events with start date order into desc. Mean today's event at top and minus one of current date and so on.

Comment: then change query to SELECT * FROM table WHERE eventstartdate <CURDATE() ORDER BY eventstartdate  DESC. This quesry will return you events from today and past days in DESC order.